# OBS recording videos at 1000 FPS

Tags: video-encoding, obs-studio

I'm currently in the midst of digitising my VHS cassettes with OBS Studio. I've set the Video Capture Device to 25 FPS but it still records at 1000 FPS taking up horrendous amounts of disk space. I've also set the FPS in Settings > Video.

[image]

```
$ ffmpeg -i 2018-02-27\ 12-20-54.mkv
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '2018-02-27 12-20-54.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:05:01.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 21528 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 1k fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:05:01.720000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Track1
      DURATION        : 00:05:01.632000000
```

I know I can re-encode the video and set the FPS to 25 but is there a more permanent solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug when recordings are saved as MKV format [and its documented in the OBS forums](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/mkv-files-are-saving-with-a-1000-frames-second.64311/) . If you want to decrease the output size, then you might want to decrease your bit rate in video settings.